# How to set display value in SAPUI 5, SmartField Value Helper field.

Tags: sapui5

Hi:  I am looking at the standard SAPUI 5 Smart Field demo:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfield/preview

I would like a field with a value helper, such as Currency on this screen, which displays the field description inside the input box instead of the field id.

Example:

1. Change the Category field from combo into a value helper (popup)
2. Get the field to display the CategoryName - or from the related table the LTXT field instead of the ID.

HowTo

1. That is easy: delete the line
    
   from the metadata.xml file.
2. ??? I have tried many, many things.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that anyone will reply, because there is most probably no good answer.I do not find this good functionality.

I think that I will need to change my ID field values for popup (value helper) fields to Description (ID) . Description need not be unique (one can have two relations to the same company with different ID's.)

By doing this we also "fix" the problem with the search ODATA command which searches the ID field. Of course users will want to search the descriptions.

In general SAPUI's value helper is not great. It is normal practice to use numerical ID's and descriptive descriptions. The description should be displayed and searched and not the ID. I found their filter generator on the popup screen nice - it is not all doom.